# jQuery UI Accordion doesn't start collapsed (collapsible:true, active:false)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

This is driving me nuts. I am using the jQuery UI Accordion and the first line stays open. I want to have it closed by default unless it is clicked. I already put in the active:false. Still the first line is not collapsed on load.

Can anybody help?

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false heightStyle: "content"
    });
});

$(function() {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        icons: icons
    });

    $("#toggle").button().click(function() {
        if ($("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons")) {
            $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", null);
        } else {
            $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code (coma missing)

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/togrrt34/1/

```
$(function() {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content",
        icons: icons
    });

    $("#toggle").button().click(function() {
        if ($("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons")) {
            $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", null);
        } else {
            $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up my messy code. Made my day. If I had an adress I would send beer.

Comment: I'm glad that's helped, you can consider my answer as accepted, later for a beer ;)